# Botpress - how to bring database values into the chat window?

Tags: node.js, bots

I'm trying to build a chatbot using Botpress. I'm a beginner, looking for your help. One of the requirements is to query database to answer questions. This is what I have tried so far:

dbconnect.js

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

var db = function dbCall(sql, values) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        oracledb.getConnection(
            {
                user          : dbConfig.user,
                password      : dbConfig.password,
                connectString : dbConfig.connectString
            },
            function(err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                connection.execute(
                    sql,
                    values,
                    {
                        maxRows: 1
                    },
                    function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                            return;
                        }
                        resolve(result);
                        doRelease(connection);
                    }
                );
            });
    });
}

// Note: connections should always be released when not needed
function doRelease(connection) {
    connection.close(
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        });
}

module.exports = db;
```

select.js

```js
var dbConnect = require('../oracledb/dbconnect');

dbConnect('select code from table1' +
    ' where id=:id', {id:'value1'}).then(function (response) {
    console.info(response.rows);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.info(error);
});
```

everything above works great, if I run select.js. How could I bring the response into the botpress chat window? I tried placing the select.js code in index.js event.reply, it doesn't work.

Thanks,

Babu.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using the promise directly in the action.

```
return dbConnect('<SQL here>=:id', { id: Id })
        .then(function(response) {
            var res = response.rows
            console.info(res);
            const newState = { ...state, status: res}

            return newState
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.info(error)
        })
```

Note that response has the resultset.